# how to get html array data to another laravel view

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

assuming that i have an HTML textbox with a name with an array:

```
<input type="hidden" id="text_array" name="text_array[]" class="test">
```

and i have a jquery code that gets the data on the textbox:

```
$('.test').each(function(){
arr = $(this).val();     
});
```

how can i get the array content and transfer it into another laravel view and then print it? i tried to get it by using `echo` my controller but i have recieved comments about printing outputs in a controller is a bad practice.

Comment: is there any way to print it out without storing it in my table?

Comment: Is there any problem with storing :D

Comment: i want to show it in another page view first before storing.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm i would recommend to use a Database or Session storage. But one idea is to save the value via JavaScript into a cookie.

Disclaimer: Untested ;)

Save the Value:

```
$('.test').each(function(){
    arr = $(this).val();  
    document.cookie = 'mycookie=' + arr +'expires=DateHere;path=/' 
});
```

Get it (somewhere):

```
$value = $request->cookie('mycookie');
```